# Improving variable estimates by reducing uncertainty

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance, estimation

I was hoping someone could assist me with a basic stats question. If I have $K_1$ samples of $R_1 = C_1 + n_1$, where $C_1$ is an unknown constant and $n_1\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)$. To make an accurate estimate of $C_1$ I can apply signal averaging such that $\frac{1}{K_1}\sum^{K_1}_1R_1 \approx C_1 + n_{k1}$, where $n_{k1}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma_1^2}{K_1}\right)$. Now assume I have another $K_1$ samples of another function $R_2 = C_1 + C_2 + n_2$, where both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are unknown constants and $n_2\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_2^2)$. If we assume $\sigma_1^2 < \sigma_2^2$, how do I improve my estimate on $C_1+C_2$ beyond that of simply applying signal averaging $\frac{1}{K_1}\sum^{K_1}_1R_2$. I have both sets of $R_1$ and $R_2$ and I know both $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$. It is also assumed that $K_1$ is fixed.

I've been told that a biased estimator might be a possible solution. Could anyone recommend a method?